# C#, problem with my reverse string method not working in main method

Tags: c#

I have used C# for 2 months and I have to write a program that will reverse a string(needs to be in a method). I need to call that method in the other class that has a main method. I have done this but when the program runs it just asks me to enter a string and it doesn't display a string in reverse please help.

Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assign3
{
    class MyStr
    {
        public string reverseStr(string Myname)
        {
            string temp = "";
            int i, j;

            Console.WriteLine("String in reverse: ");
            for (j = 0, i = Myname.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--, j++)
                temp += Myname[i];

            return temp;
        }

    }
}
```

and the next class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assign3
{
    class Test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string answer;
            MyStr aString = new MyStr();
            //MyStr.reverseStr(string temp);
            //Console.WriteLine(aString);
            Console.WriteLine("enter a string");
            Console.ReadLine();
            answer = aString.reverseStr("");
            Console.WriteLine(answer);
        Console.WriteLine(aString.reverseStr(i);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to get this method to output the string in reverse. Please help me understand what I did wrong and please guide me in the right direction to correct this.

Comment: Console.ReadLine returns what the user types. If you don't get this result you can't reverse anything.

Comment: Try echoing the input, enclosed in some delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't examined your string reversing algorithm at all, but in these two lines:

```
Console.ReadLine();
answer = aString.reverseStr("");
```

You get a string from the user with ReadLine(), which you simply throw away since you didn't store it in a variable.  Then you are asking reverseStr() to reverse a blank string, which is probably not what you want.

It should look more like:

```
string response = Console.ReadLine();
answer = aString.reverseStr(response);
```

Or you could combine the two in one line:

```
answer = aString.reverseStr(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't do anything with the user's input:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

And you're reversing an empty string:

```
answer = aString.reverseStr("");
```

Store the user's input and reverse that instead:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
answer = aString.reverseStr(input);
```

Comment: up one for mentioning the unused j variable. while that does not answering the question, it was definitely worth mentioning!

Comment: Sorry, I inadvertently updated your answer instead of mine :-(

Answer (score 1):

you can reverse string in main method like this

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter a string");
        string stng =Console.ReadLine();
        char[] revArray = stng.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse( revArray );
        Console.WriteLine(revArray);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Add a `Console.ReadLine();` at the end so we can see your correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You are feeding the method with an empty string `aString.reverseStr("")`. You must read the user input into a variable and pass this one to the reverse method.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
answer = aString.reverseStr(input);
```

You can remove the `j` variable as you are not using it. The `Console.WriteLine("String in reverse: ");` should be in the main method, where all the other console input/output is. The `reverseStr` method should only do the reversing stuff and not have side effects. This would be cleaner.

---

You can pass a parameter through the constructor like this

```
class MyStr
{
    private string _name;

    // Constructor. Has same name as class. Doesn't have a return type.
    public MyStr(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public string ReverseStr()
    {
        string temp = "";
        int i, j;

        for (j = 0, i = _name.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--, j++)
            temp += _name[i];

        return temp;
    }
}
```

And you would call it like this

```
var myStr = new MyStr(input);
string result = myStr.ReverseStr();
```

Comment: Thank you everyone who helped me with this, it is now working perfectly. How can I use a constructor method to take the input string as the parameter and assign it to the private string of my class?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no built in functions to do that. You could use a char array and reverse the array and then get the string back.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input;
            string output;
            MyStr aString = new MyStr();
            Console.WriteLine("enter a string");
           input = Console.ReadLine();
            output = aString.reverseStr(input);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

class MyStr
{
    public string reverseStr(string Myname)
    {
        char[] arr = Myname.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        return new string(arr);
    }

}
}
```

Alternatively, instead of MyStr class, you could define an extension for string. And your calling statement will be as simple as

```
string output = input.Reverse();
```

Extension method as follows and it can be used everywhere without instantiating a class by just using string variable.

```
public static class StringUtility
{
    public static string Reverse(this string input)
    {
        char[] arr = input.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        return new string(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thank you, and is it possible to call a constructor the same way a method is called? is there a reason why I would put my code in a constructor instead of a method?